# Where can I find the source code for Quorum, the permissioned implementation of Ethereum supporting data privacy?

Tags: go-ethereum, permissioned-chain, quorum

Where can I find the source code for Quorum, the permissioned Go implementation of Ethereum supporting data privacy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is at https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum

There are related repos at the parent https://github.com/jpmorganchase, such as quorum-examples, quorum-docs, constellation, and cakeshop.

https://www.jpmorgan.com/country/US/EN/Quorum has a summary and other information such as:

- Quorum is an **enterprise-focused** version of Ethereum.
- Quorum is ideal for any application requiring **high speed** and **high throughput** processing of **private transactions** within a **permissioned** group of known participants. Quorum addresses specific challenges to **blockchain technology adoption within the financial industry, and beyond**.
- [Quorum whitepaper](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-docs/blob/master/Quorum%20Whitepaper%20v0.1.pdf)
- contact email: quorum_info@jpmorgan.com

Answer (score 3):

From [JP Morgan released its implementation of a permissioned version of Ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/5eljjs/jp_morgan_released_its_implementation_of_a/), the GitHub repository for Quorum is at https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum.

---

From the repository:

Quorum is an Ethereum-based distributed ledger protocol with transaction/contract privacy and a new consensus mechanism.

Key enhancements:

- QuorumChain - a new consensus model based on majority voting
- Constellation - a peer-to-peer encrypted message exchange
- Peer Security - node/peer permissioning using smart contracts

## Architecture

[image: Quorum architecture]

Answer (score 0):

Please see my github link https://github.com/prateektiwari7/Quorum-Example

You can see folder in my github where there is easy steps to use this chain and truffle example.

And for installation of Quorum you can visit 
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples

And to do published smartContact over Quorum here is best Example 
https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

Hope you like it.