# Is it possible to build a private (permissioned) blockchain with Ethereum?

Tags: permissioned-chain

Ethereum is a great blockchain, but for some services the transaction fee is prohibitively too expensive. Is there any project and/or guideline on making Ethereum so it works on permissioned blockchains - i.e., with the consensus algorithm and mining replaced by majority vote? Would a simple fork of the network work fine, or is there any reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10250/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-quorum-the-permissioned-implementation-of

Comment: See also http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10717/620

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**, [Quorum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10250/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-quorum-the-permissioned-implementation-of) is one open source example.

The Ethereum wiki has a detailed section on [Consortium Chain Development](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Consortium-Chain-Development) including suggestions for consensus algorithms:

> In a private chain context, there are three consensus algorithms that
>   make the most sense:
>
> **Proof of authority** - essentially, one client with one particular
>   private key makes all of the blocks
>
> **PBFT** (or some other traditional
>   byzantine-fault-tolerant consensus algorithm)
>
> **DPOS** (or some other
>   chain-based limited-validator consensus algorithm)

Regarding [P2P Networking](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Consortium-Chain-Development#p2p-networking):

> A private chain may want to either use the same networking code (but
>   with a different network ID set in the config file), or use an
>   alternative type of network; the most likely alternative is a design
>   where every node connects directly to every other node (quite feasible
>   and likely optimal in networks with under ~20 nodes).

Regarding transaction fees, it highlights:

> **Important note:** "gas" and "ether" are NOT the same thing. Gas is a
>   mechanism that allows computation inside the EVM to be
>   deterministically metered, ie. for contracts to deterministically
>   restrict calls to some fixed number of computational steps. Ether is a
>   way of paying transaction fees, which are expected to be proportional
>   to gas consumption. The Bitcoin analog of ether is BTC, the Bitcoin
>   analog of gas is the number of bytes that a transaction takes up in a
>   block; in Ethereum, measuring bytes alone is not enough as you also
>   need to measure computation, hence the concept of gas. On a private
>   chain, you do not need to use ether to pay for gas; you can come up
>   with alternate rulesets, including for example simply requiring every
>   transaction to have a maximum gas limit of 1 million.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HydraChain (https://github.com/HydraChain/hydrachain). It is a permissioned blockchain based on Ethereum.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Monax (formerly Eris). They were IMO the first ones to explore private [permissioned chains](https://monax.io/explainers/permissioned_blockchains/) with eris:db and the system is compatible with Ethereum as they use the EVM and Solidity.

Comment: Now known as Hyperledger Burrow - https://hyperledger.org/projects/hyperledger-burrow.